# How can I link to a page and have the page auto-refresh when the user gets to it?

Tags: html

After users register for my site, I want to link them to my homepage and then I need that page to refresh.

Anyone know how to do that via the link? (Not by adding code to the homepage.)

Answer (score 4):

You could add a random string to the link:

```
www.example.com/home.html?update=123459393203940459
```

this will cause the browser to re-load the page and not use a possible cached version.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that one by call a Javascript function on the body onload function. The HTML for that one is as following

Place that one inside the  tag

function redirectPage()
{
   window.location.href='somepage.html';
}

Replace the  with the following